# Add files to firebase cloud functions and typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Some functions I have deployed need non-code files (binary executables and certificates). What's the best way to deploy them together with the functions?

I used to copy them into the `js` folder during the build script but it has been a month or so that during deployment the server tries to rerun the build script which fails because of the missing local files. Meaning I can't deploy anymore with my old build script.

Can I prevent Firebase from rebuilding in the cloud? Or are there other ways to deploy non-code files? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to store those binaries in the cloud storage bucket and access them using firebase admin sdk with `admin.storage()`. Or Have you checked this [docs for The firebase.json file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#the_firebasejson_file)

Comment: @RohitKharche so that every time I need to run an executable, I have to download it first? Maybe there is a way to deploy them via firebase.json, not via build script.

Comment: Yes you can also make it work by modifying firebase.json file and adding includes property like : `"includes": [ "bin/**" ]` after `ignore` field.

Comment: I will try. It's just nice if I could copy local files from outside the project (i.e. Dropbox folder) on build.

Comment: Maybe there is a better way to manage certificates? Env variables?

Comment: Does my comment help ? Acknowledge if it did so I will post as an answer, if not then we can solve further.

Comment: Hi @RohitKharche, to be honest, I haven't looked into it since I don't need to update those functions which use files. Where would you store certificate files?

Comment: @RohitKharche the time has come to find a solution for this deployment issue. The problem with your suggestion is that my functions and app project are separate. Meaning that for this project I only use `firebase deploy --only functions`. I tried to figure out if even with the "functions" node in `firebase.json` I can specify things like `includes` but I couldn't find any related documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that, without doing anything, all the folders inside your `functions` folder get deployed. This means that I simply moved my `binaries` folder inside the `functions` folder. In my case, since the function code was in a subfolder, I had to reference the file from the code in this way:

```js
const exePath = path.join(
  __dirname,
  '..',
  '..', // extra move because in a subfolder
  'binaries',
  'exe-file-name'
);
```

Remember that, if you deploy the code from CLI, you can download the deployed .zip file from the [Google Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list) to double-check the relative paths.